# In Classical Reporting, showing table with columns aligned

Tags: report, abap

I am trying to use UNDER in following way:

```
write:/ wa_tab-subject UNDER 'Subjects', wa_tab-part UNDER 'Parts', wa_tab-mark under 'Marks', sy-uline.
```

and in  **TOP-OF-PAGE**  block,

```
write:/ 'Subjects' COLOR 1, sy-vline, 'Parts' COLOR 1, sy-vline, 'Marks' COLOR 1.
```

But the values displayed don't come under the respective columns and even wa_tab-part is not displayed. So, how to display the table in proper format?

and the other question is how to get the correct line-size for classical reporting?

Comment: /methinks "The 1970s called, they want their reports back"... :-)

Comment: Did you try to put the write from `top-of-page` direct before your write? (Just to test, if the top-of-page is the problem). I think there are problems, if there are writes after the line where you define the location. Another possible problem: How long is your `wa_tab-subject`? Longer then 8 characters? (the length of 'subjects').

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

SY-LINSZ gives you the current linesize, whether you've defined it in the REPORT statement or not.

I think your problem with `UNDER` is that your first `WRITE` writes `'Subjects' COLOR 1`.  See if it helps to use `FORMAT COLOR` instead?  The documentation says:

"The data object other_dobj must be written exactly as in the corresponding WRITE statement, including all possible offset/length specifications and so on."

Maybe you're falling foul of "... and so on".